# How to define a connection string in c#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I am fresher in development so I want to know about connection string ?

and I also want to know about connection string and where is define or in program how can define it.

Comment: [http://www.connectionstrings.com/](http://www.connectionstrings.com/)

Comment: A connection string is just a driver selection with some arguments which are required for your DBMS. Since you did not name your database that is all what anybody can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstly add assembly in Reference

```
System.Configuration
```

then add connection string in app.config file

```
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="ItemDB" connectionString="Data Source=webpc;Initial Catalog=ItemMaster; Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=teknosys@123"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />     
    </connectionStrings>
```

after that use in your codebehid class where you want it

```
  SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ItemDB"].ConnectionString);
```

use it

Answer (score 1):

Add connection to your web config file as

```
 <connectionStrings>
 <add name="Dbconnection" 
   connectionString="Server=localhost; Database=OnlineShopping ; Integrated   Security=True" ;   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Then in aspx.cs page call this connection

```
  string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Dbconnection"].ConnectionString;
```

Call this connection string to bind grid or dataset

```
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connStr);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(connStr, con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "sp_taskdisplay";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        adapter.Fill(ds);
        drp_down.DataSource = ds;
```